# I dont understand the context here

Tags: android

I am studying an application where two fragments communicate in the MainActivity through interface. If we wirte something in FirstFragment 
SecondFragment shows that FirstFragmentListener is an interface which is implemented in MainActivity.

This is the part of code in first fragment that arises my confusion

```java
    package mchehab.com.fragmentscommunication;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

        private EditText editText;
        private Button buttonSendMessage;
        private FirstFragmentListener firstFragmentListener;

        public FirstFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
            editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            buttonSendMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSendMessage);

            buttonSendMessage.setOnClickListener(e -> {
                if(firstFragmentListener != null){
                    firstFragmentListener.getMessage(editText.getText().toString());
                }
            });
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if(context instanceof FirstFragmentListener){
                firstFragmentListener = (FirstFragmentListener) context;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if(context instanceof FirstFragmentListener){
                firstFragmentListener = (FirstFragmentListener) context;
            }
        }
```

here  what i understand context is the context of activity, in this case MainActivity.

```java
firstFragmentListener = (FirstFragmentListener) context;
```

but why they are casting context in this line. 
Why should they need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case MainActivity implements FirstFragmentListener so when you cast context to FirstFragmentListener you can use methods from this interface.
This is an old (and currently out of date) approach.

Use shared ViewModel to communicate between fragments. See: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing

Comment: thank you so much. this is the simple thing , that i couldn't catch

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, the `MainActivity` looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FirstFragmentListener {...}
```

and they need this `FirstFragmentListener`. For your understanding, the full code can be:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context
firstFragmentListener = (FirstFragmentListener) mainActivity
```